# Why I got error ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified when print report in APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a Report queries under shared components in oracle apex
and the report tested and working fine when test the report from the wizard
also I created a button and put the report URL to call the report when click the button

this is the select statement its simple query and no LOB columns :

```
    SELECT PATIENT_NO,
DATE_OF_BIRTH,
BIRTH_PLACE,
FIRST_NAME_A||''||FATHER_NAME_A||''||GRANDFATHER_NAME_A||''||LAST_NAME_A as "Patient name" 
FROM MR_FILES
```

this is the report link

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.:PRINT_REPORT=MRN%20Files
```

when click the button report not working and show this error

```
 Error processing request.
Contact your application administrator.
Technical Info (only available for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.UNHANDLED_ERROR
ora_sqlcode: -22275
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-22275: invalid LOB locator specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WPG_DOCLOAD", line 51
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_RENDER_QUERY", line 1966
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
component.id: 200024000000000
component.name: Global Page
error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WPG_DOCLOAD", line 51
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_RENDER_QUERY", line 1966
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW", line 3004
```

How to solve the error please ?